What are all the matrices $A$ such that $A^2=0?$
I wonder How to find all the $n \times n$ matrices $A$ such that $A^2=0$ given $n$.
When $n=1$ the only option is $A=[0]$, When $n=2$ there two such $A$ in the general form and these have the form:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}\ 
  \pm i\sqrt{ab}&a\\
  b&\mp i\sqrt{ab}
\end{array}
\right] $$
for all complex $a,b$,
The question is: How to find a general form for any $n$?
It seems that for given $n$ there are $n$ general forms for such matrices but finding the general form of $n=3$ seem to be difficult
One need to solve these nine non linear system of equations
$$ \left[
\begin{array}\ 
  a_1^2+a_2\cdot a_4+ a_3\cdot a_7 &a_1\cdot a_2+a_2\cdot a_5 + a_3 \cdot a_8  &a_1\cdot a_3+ a_2 \cdot a_6 +a_3 \cdot a_9\\
   a_1 \cdot a_4 + a_4 \cdot a_5 + a_6 \cdot a_7&a_5^2 +a_2\cdot a_4+ a_6 \cdot a_8  &a_3\cdot a_4+ e_5 \cdot a_6 +a_6\cdot a_9\\
   a_1 \cdot a_7 + a_4 \cdot a_8+a_7\cdot a_9& a_2\cdot a_7  +a_5 \cdot a_8 + a_8 \cdot a_9&a_9^2 +a_3\cdot a_7 +a_6\cdot a_8 \\
\end{array}
\right] =\left[
\begin{array}\ 
  0 &  0&0\\
   0& 0 &0\\
   0& 0  &0\\
\end{array}
\right]  $$

Such matrix is called Nilpotent Matrix

They are the matrices such that $\text{range}(A)\subseteq \ker(A)$.  There are obviously infinitely many such $A$, and also they do not form a vector space of their own (See for example that $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ are both nilpotent of index 2, yet their sum is not).  There is an easy way to construct examples of such matrices, but to describe all such you won't get much more detailed than the incredibly general statement made at the start.

@JMoravitz It's easy to describe their similarity type...

@LuckyChouhan Not exactly. For a nilpotent matrix one can have $A^2\ne 0$. This are nilpotent matrices of index two, an important distinction since those are more easy to describe that general nilpotent matrices.

maybe here you could find some examples: Grassmann number

We can argue directly, without appealing to the Jordan normal form theorem; this kind of argument is used in some proofs of the Jordan normal form theorem, which reduce from the general case to the nilpotent case, e.g. Terence Tao's approach here.
If $T : V \to V$ is a linear map on a vector space $V$ (not necessarily finite-dimensional) then $T^2 = 0$ iff $\text{im}(T) \subseteq \ker(T)$. So the data of the map $T$ is determined by the data of

a subspace $\ker(T)$ of $V$, and
an injection $V/\text{ker}(T) \hookrightarrow \ker(T)$.

Choose a basis $\{ e_i \}$ of the image of $V/\ker(T)$ in $\ker(T)$, and lift it to a set $\{ f_i \}$ of linearly independent vectors in $V$, so that $T(f_i) = e_i$. Then complete $\{ e_i \}$ to a basis $\{ e_i, g_j \}$ of $\ker(T)$. Altogether the vectors $\{ e_i, f_i, g_j \}$ form a basis of $V$, and in this basis $T$ has a particularly simple form:
$$T(f_i) = e_i, T(e_i) = T(g_j) = 0.$$
Equivalently, $T$ expressed in this basis is block-diagonal with blocks given by $2 \times 2$ Jordan blocks $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (corresponding to its action on $\{ e_i, f_i \}$ for a fixed $i$) or zero (corresponding to its action on $\{ g_j \}$). Note that we do not need to assume $V$ is finite-dimensional anywhere in this argument!
Specializing to the case that $V = K^n$ for $K$ an arbitrary field, it follows that the matrices $A$ satisfying $A^2 = 0$ are exactly the matrices similar / conjugate to a matrix of the above block-diagonal form. This classification naturally splits up into $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor + 1$ cases depending on the rank of $A$ (equivalently, the number of Jordan blocks), which can be any integer between $0$ and $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$, inclusive.
Even when $n = 2$ and $K = \mathbb{C}$ I wouldn't phrase the classification the way you phrased it, because it involves operations that are not defined over arbitrary fields. The classification in this case, over an arbitrary field, is that either $A = 0$ or $A$ is similar to the Jordan block $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. For $2 \times 2$ matrices this is equivalent to the condition that $\text{tr}(A) = \det(A) = 0$, meaning if we write
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$
then $a + d = 0$ and $ad - bc = 0$. We can split into two cases here: if $b \neq 0$ then such matrices have the form
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ \frac{-a^2}{b} & -a \end{bmatrix}$$
and if $b = 0$ then we instead get matrices of the form
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ c & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
This can also be done via a direct calculation with the condition $A^2 = 0$, but this approach doesn't easily generalize to $n \times n$ matrices. You might consider this less elegant than your parameterization but now it works over any field!

It is easy to describe the similarity type of all such matrices, using canonical forms.
If an $m\times m$ matrix $A$ satisfies $A^n=0$, then its minimal polynomial is $t^k$ some for $1\leq k\leq n$, and hence its characteristic polynomial is $(-1)^mt^m$. In particular, the characteristic polynomial splits, so $A$ has a Jordan Canonical Form. This form will have blocks with diagonal entries equal to $0$.
Fix $k$, and let $J_k(0)$ be a $k\times k$ Jordan block corresponding to $0$; that is, the $k\times k$ matrix of the form
$$J_k(0) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{array}\right)$$.
For each partition of $m$, $m=k_1+k_2+\cdots + k_r$, $r\geq 1$, $k_r\geq k_{r-1}\geq\cdots\geq k_r\geq 1$, the block diagonal matrix
$$A(k_1,\ldots,k_r) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
J_{k_1}(0) &  & \\
 & \ddots & \\
 &  & J_{k_r}(0)
\end{array}\right)$$
has the desired property. Distinct partitions give non-similar matrices with the property, and every matrix with the property is similar to a matrix of the form $A(k_1,\ldots,k_r)$ for some partition $m=k_1+\cdots+k_r$ of $m$. This matrix will satisfy $A^{k_1}=0$, and for all $0\lt t\lt k_1$, $A^{t}\neq 0$.
Thus, every $m\times m$ nilpotent matrix has the form
$$PA(k_1,\ldots,k_r)P^{-1}$$
where $m=k_1+\cdots + k_r$, $k_1\geq k_2\geq\cdots\geq k_r\gt 0$ is a partition of $m$, and $P$ is an invertible $m\times m$ matrix. This matrix will satisfy $M^{k_1}=0$, and $M^t\neq 0$ for all $t$ with $0\lt t \lt k_1$.
For $A^2=0$, the only partitions allowed require $k_1\leq 2$. So your matrix will be similar to an upper triangular matrix of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
where you have a bunch of $J_2(0)$ diagonal blocks, and the rest of the entries are $0$.
The $2\times 2$ matrices you describe have this form. For the nonzero matrices, start with
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
Then an arbitrary invertible matrix $P$ will have
$$P = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right),\qquad P^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{d}{ad-bc} & \frac{-b}{ad-bc}\\
\frac{-c}{ad-bc} & \frac{a}{ad-bc}
\end{array}\right)$$
with $ad-bc\neq 0$, so
$$PAP^{-1} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{-ac}{ad-bc} & \frac{a^2}{ad-bc}\\
\frac{-c^2}{ad-bc} & \frac{ac}{ad-bc}
\end{array}\right)$$
and you can verify that this has the form for suitable choices of your parameters.

This is nitpicky but using Jordan normal form is potentially circular here, because some proofs of that theorem need to analyze nilpotent matrices as a special case to establish the full result (e.g. the approach used by Terence Tao here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/10/12/the-jordan-normal-form-and-the-euclidean-algorithm/).

@QiaochuYuan Not really: I'm not using this to establish the existence of the Jordan Canonical Form, so how could it be "circular"? I'm using the JCF to describe certain matrices, once the JCF has been established.

OP asked about matrices such that $A^{\color{red}2}=0$. Those matrices (or its similarity type) should be easier to describe, doesn't it?

@jjagmath: Yes, doing so presently.

The equation $\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\ c & d\end{array}\right)^2=0$ yields the conditions
$$
\begin{split}
a^2+bc=bc+d^2=0;\\
(a+d)b=(a+d)c=0.
\end{split}
$$
The first line yields $a^2=d^2$ or $(a+d)(a-d)=0$, while the second yields either $a+d=0$ or, if $a+d\neq 0$, $b=c=0$. But $b=c=0$ implies $a^2=d^2=0$ and hence $a=b=c=d=0$. Thus a non-zero solution must have $a+d=0$ and $bc=-a^2$ (which as $a=-d$ implies $bc=-d^2$ also). I suspect the OP found these equations and deduced their solutions from them, but doesn't quite get the general solution: If we let $N$ of $2\times 2$ matrices which square to zero is
$$
N= \left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\ -a^2/b & -a\end{array}\right) : b\neq 0\right\}\cup \left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0\\ c & 0 \end{array}\right): c \text{ arbitrary}\right\}
$$
In particular, there are many matrices which square to 0 with all real entries. In fact, to understand the set $N$ when working over $\mathbb R$ you get a nicer description by changing variables to $(x,y,z)$ where $x=a, y=(b-c)/2, z=(b+c)/2$. Then the equation $a^2+bc=0$ becomes $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$, or $z^2=x^2+y^2$, a right-angled cone in $\mathbb R^3$:
If
$$
J_1 = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right), \quad J_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 &0 \end{array}\right), \quad J_3 = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{array}\right)
$$
then we have
$$
N= \left\{xJ_1+yJ_2+zJ_3: z^2=x^2+y^2\right\}
$$
This direct approach becomes cumbersome for $n>2$ however, and it is better to note that if $A^2=0$ then $B=PAP^{-1}$ also satisfies $B^2=0$. Thus one can ask seek simple representatives of the similarity classes of matrices which satisfy $A^2=0$. Let $K=\{v \in \mathbb R^n: Av=0\}$ and $I = \{v \in \mathbb R^n: v=Au, \text{ some } u \in \mathbb R^n\}$. Then $A^2=0$ if and only if $I\subseteq K$.
Now if $I\subseteq K$, then we may pick a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_l\}$ of $I$ and extend it to a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ of $K$. Since, for each $1\leq i\leq l$ $v_i \in I$ we may find some $u_i \in \mathbb R^n$ with $Au_i = v_i$.
Claim:$B=\{u_1,\ldots,u_l\}\cup \{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^n$:
We first show that $B$ is linearly independent: Suppose that $\sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_iv_i+ \sum_{j=1}^l \mu_j u_j=0$. Then applying $A$, since $Av_i=0$ for all $i$, $0=\sum_{j=1}^l \mu_j Au_j = \sum_{j=1}^l \mu_j v_j$. Since $\{v_1,\ldots,v_l\}$ is linearly independent, it follows $\mu_j=0$ for all $j$. But then our linear dependence becomes $\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i v_i=0$, and since $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is linearly independent we must have $\lambda_i=0$ for all $i$ $(1\leq i\leq k)$ also, and $B$ is linearly independent as required.
To see that $B$ spans $\mathbb R^n$, suppose $w \in \mathbb R^n$. Then $Aw \in I$ so that $Aw = \sum_{j=1}^l\mu_j Au_j$ for some scalars $\mu_j$. But then $A(w-\sum_{j=1}^l \mu_j u_j)=0$ so that $w-\sum_{j=1}^l \mu_j u_j \in K$. But then $w-\sum_{j=1}^l \mu_j u_j = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i$ for some scalars $\lambda_i$, and hence $w = \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i v_i + \sum_{j=1}^l \mu_ju_j$ and so $B$ spans $\mathbb R^n$ as claimed. Note that $|B|=k+l = \dim(\mathbb R^n)$, so that we must have $l=n-k\leq k$, that is, $k$ determines $l$ and $2k\geq n$, so that $n/2\leq k \leq n$.
Now if we let $B'$ be the ordered basis $\{u_1,\ldots,u_l,v_{l+1},\ldots,v_k,v_1,\ldots,v_l\}$the matrix of $A$ with respect to the basis $B'$ is just
$$
R_k = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0_{k,l} & 0_{k,k}\\ I_{l,l} & 0_{l,k} \end{array}\right)
$$
Thus we see that there are $\lceil (n+1)/2 \rceil$ similarity classes of matrices satisfying $A^2=0$, where for $k$ with $n/2\leq k\leq n$ the matrices $R_k$ give representatives of those classes.
You can also reorder the basis as $\{u_1,Au_1,u_2,Au_2,\ldots,u_l, Au_l, v_{l+1},\ldots,v_k\}$, and with this ordering the matrix of $A$ is given by
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} J_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \hline  0 & \ddots &  & \vdots \\ \hline \vdots & & J_2 & 0 \\ \hline 0 & \cdots & & 0_{k-l,k-l}\end{array}\right)
$$
that is, you obtain the representatives in "Jordan form".

$A^2=0$ means $\operatorname{Im}(A)\subset \operatorname{ker}(A)$, and this implies $\operatorname{rank}(A)\le \frac{n}{2}$.
For $n=2$ or $3$, the above is equivalent to $\operatorname{rank}(A)\le 1$.  Now for matrices of rank $\le 1$ we have
$$A^2 = \operatorname{trace}(A)\cdot A$$
We know the description of matrices of rank $1$: $\ a_{ij} = p_i \cdot q_j$ for some vectors $p$, $q$. Moreover $ \operatorname{trace}(A)= p\cdot q$.  So we get the solution for $n=2$ or $3$:  take two orthogonal vectors $p$, $q$, and form the matrix $p\boxtimes q$.
$\bf{Added:}$ In the same spirit, we can get a (surjective) description of all matrices $A$ with $A^2 = 0$.  Take $B\in M_{n,k}$ and $C$ in $C \in M_{k,n}$ and form the matrix $A \colon = B\cdot C$. We get $A^2 = B(CB) C$.  Therefore if $CB = 0$ then $A^2=0$.  Now this can be done with $k =[ \frac{n}{2}]$.

A matrix $A$ with $A^2 = 0$ has a nullspace $N$. Let $N\oplus N^\bot$ be an orthogonal decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for an arbitrary inner product. There exists some injective linear map $L : N^\bot \to N$ with $A(x'\oplus x'') = (Lx''\oplus 0)$. The matrices $A$ can be parametrized by the arbitrary choice of injective $L : N^\bot \to N$. Using rotations you can fix the choice of $N$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}\times 0^{k}$, reducing to an analysis of injective linear maps $\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ for each valid value of $k$, which are described by their singular value decomposition.
